# OpenCV multiply objects in/out counting

Tags: opencv, count, tracking

I've wrote a opencv code for multiply moving objects detection and tracking with background substraction. Now i need to count objects who went in or out. I can get coordinates of all objects who are in camera/screen. Camera is set above object http://prntscr.com/25wgg6 . Is there any good algorythm to count in/out multi objects, or get the direction of objects?

Comment: Ah, indeed, Optical Flow. I had a short lapse of memory. [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4496123/176769).

Comment: Similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461211/know-how-many-people-are-on-a-video/18461522#18461522).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an example do that in samples\c\motempl.c